# Get profile picture creation date from user table in FQL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

How can I get my friends profile pictures creation date using `FQL multi-query`?

I wrote below query:

```
SELECT src_small, src_big, src FROM photo WHERE src IN
(SELECT pic_square, pic_small, pic_big, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN
(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) )
```

but it says:

```
{

  "error": {
  "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column.    Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
  "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
  "code": 604
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You can use a column in the WHERE clause only if it's marked as "indexable", in you example

  (`SELECT src_small, src_big, src FROM photo WHERE src IN`)

 `src` is not `indexable` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/

Answer (score 2):

> from comment by Arjuna Del Toso:
>
> You can use a column in the WHERE clause only if it's marked as "indexable"

Not, that is not totally correct.

You need *at least one* indexable column in your where clause – once you have that, you can use other, non-indexed columns as well to further restrict the result.

---

Since the user’s current profile picture is always the *album cover photo* of their *Profile Pictures* album, we can use that to get the `object_id` of the profile picture of our friends, and than use that to select the info we want from the `photo` table:

```
SELECT owner, src_small, created FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (
  SELECT cover_object_id FROM album WHERE owner IN (
    SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()
  ) AND name = 'Profile Pictures'
)
```